# Silverlight Application for Scanner, "COM automation is not available."

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis

COM automation is not available. in silverlight

Comment: The usual problem with an approach like this is giving everybody that needs to scan a document the key to the server room and a plane ticket to get there.  Read the Note in the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure elevated trust is enabled in your application.  I think when running under localhost, that feature is automatically turned on.  See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx